# polymer custom events fired by child element not caught by parent element

Tags: polymer, custom-events

i'm trying to fire a custom event from a child element to its parent but its not working using listeners object. it works using annotated events but that isn't applicable in most situations.How can i use listeners object in this case. here's some code to illustrate the problem:

```
   <!--in child element's dom..-->

<dom-module id="searchresult-controller">
    <template>
        <style>
            ...
        </style>
    </template>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        Polymer({
            is: "searchresult-controller",

               ready: function(){
                  this.sendSignal();
            },

            sendSignal: function() {
                 this.fire('msg', {data: 'i love polymer'});
             }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>

<!-- in parent -->
 <dom-module id="search-controllers">
<template>
    <style>
       ...
    </style>
     <searchresult-controller></searchresult-controller>
     <result-view></result-view>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Polymer({
        is: "search-controllers",

        listeners: {
            'msg': '_showAlert'
        },
         _showAlert: function(e) {
            console.log(e.detail.data);
        }

    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try firing the event from `searchresult-controller` on `attached` and not `ready`?

`ready` might be too soon for `search-controllers` to handle since, [according to the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#lifecycle-callbacks), listeners set in the `listeners` object are set during the `attached` lifecycle event.

My guess is `searchresult-controller`'s `ready` event happens before `search-controllers`'s `attached` event.

Comment: thanks a ton esp for the reference to d docs. Still concerning events, i tried firing an iron-signal event from a main.js like so, 
var event = new CustomEvent('iron-signal', {'detail' : {name: 'action', data: "foo"}});
document.dispatchEvent(event);
while another element listened using iron-signals but no results. How can i do this, and are there any good books out there on polymer that you can recommend cos i need to build a strong foundation with understanding on the basics of building apps with polymer thanks.

Comment: how did you set up your `<iron-signals>` and more specifically how did you try to listen to the `action` event? I don't know about books, but I find that reading the [Polymer components source code on GitHub](https://github.com/PolymerElements) teaches you a lot.